# What's the point of the Owin assemblies separation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

(I think) I get what OWIN is about, it's an abstraction over web servers so that web applications developed for one web server can be run on other web servers too.

But there's another abstraction on top of that which I don't get. There is an Owin package in the Nuget gallery which only contains the IAppBuilder interface and nothing else. The implementation of that and many, many other things are in other Microsoft packages (the Katana project AFAIK). What's the point of this simple assembly? The only package I know of that uses Owin is SignalR, which has a hard dependency on both Owin and the Katana assemblies. So this separation seems to provide no additional portability at all.

There is also an Owin repository on GitHub which seems to contain a reimplementation of some Katana features. (See [this](https://github.com/owin-contrib/owin-hosting/blob/master/src/main/Owin.Builder/AppBuilder.cs) vs. [this](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Builder/AppBuilder.cs).) If I develop a package to run on one Owin, it won't run on the other. What's the point here?

Comment: [OWIN FAQ](https://github.com/owin/owin/wiki/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAppBuilder isn't in the OWIN spec, but Microsoft needed/wanted something to use as a focal point for registering middleware. There's a long issue on github about it as well:

https://github.com/owin/owin/issues/19

Comment: "That this assembly exists is an historical accident/mistake." All my questions are answered :)